# HTML5 preloader video (progress bar fills up faster than the video ends with a file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem. Progress bar fills up faster than the video ends with a file. The progress bar is full, and the video is not finished yet.

```
$('.media_audio_player').bind('timeupdate' ,function() {
    var id = $(this);
    var idn = 'AudioBar_wrap\+'+this.id.split('rolf')[1];
    var canvas = document.getElementById(idn);

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var lingrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,150);
        var fWidth = (id.get(0).currentTime / id.get(0).duration) * (canvas.clientWidth);

        if (fWidth > 0) {
            lingrad.addColorStop(0, '#ebbdbd');
            lingrad.addColorStop(0.5, '#dd6060');
            lingrad.addColorStop(1, '#dc4c4c');
            ctx.fillStyle = lingrad;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, fWidth, 150);
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

also you can make next:

```
var fWidth = (id.get(0).currentTime / id.get(0).duration) * (CanvasWidth);
```

where CanvasWidth= length canvas, which is populated before the file finishes playing.
in your case:

```
var fWidth = (id.get(0).currentTime / id.get(0).duration) * (300);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var progress = Math.floor(video.currentTime) / Math.floor(video.duration);
controls.progress[0].style.width = Math.floor(progress * controls.total.width()) + "px";
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but not worked right. width my canvas = 422, but canvas is filled as if its length is equal to 300.
i checked components (currentTime, duration and canvas.clientWidth), when sound play. all right, but draws not right...
why?

P.s.: you can see work script here (http://testwork.ru/10001/media.php) - try play audio file on page...

Comment: width my canvas = 422, but he create on 300 px... Why?